# Argument of type '(res: bookContent) => void' is not assignable

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to TS and getting this typeerror in a useEffect() that calls my database. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I read that it is because I am not returning anything but this function doesn't need to return anything... I could be wrong though.

```
Argument of type '(res: bookContent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: bookContent | undefined) => void | PromiseLike<void>'.
  Types of parameters 'res' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'bookContent | undefined' is not assignable to type 'bookContent'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'bookContent'
```

Here is the code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    services.bookData
      .getBookInfo(bookID)
      .then((res: bookContent) => {
        if (res) {
          setContent({
            id: res.id,
            name: res.name,
            info: res.info,
            type: res.type,
          });
          dispatch(bookContentThunk(content));
        }
      })
      .catch((err: any) => {
        throw new Error(`Error in retrieving book details. ${err}`);
      });
  }, [user.status]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getBookInfo` can return either `bookContent | undefined` (also would advise to add an Uppercase to the `bookContent` type to avoid confusion).

You assign a function that describes its argument as `(res: bookContent)`. Typescript is complaining that `res` can also be `undefined`, hence `Types of parameters 'res' and 'value' are incompatible.`.

To fix your problem, you should make `res` as `bookContent | undefined`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    services.bookData
      .getBookInfo(bookID)
      .then((res: bookContent | undefined) => {
        if (res) {
          setContent({
            id: res.id,
            name: res.name,
            info: res.info,
            type: res.type,
          });
          dispatch(bookContentThunk(content));
        }
      })
      .catch((err: any) => {
        throw new Error(`Error in retrieving book details. ${err}`);
      });
  }, [user.status]);
```